# How can I use endings like -네요 and -거든요 when using 합쇼체 or 해라체?

Tags: grammar, verb-endings, speech-levels

The sentence endings -네(요) and -거든(요) can easily be used when speaking in 해요체 and 해체:

> 비가 오네
>
> A: 정장 입었네요...
>
>  B: 면접 있거든요.

But how can I express the same meaning if I'm speaking in 합쇼체 or 해라체?

(Or in 하오체 or 하게체, for that matter, though I never use them).

Answer (score 2):

하십시오체(formerly 합쇼체) doesn't have a dedicated "I just realized," describing ending like -네요 or -든요, mostly because these kind of endings are only used when talking to oneself(in 해체) or in informal situations(in 해체 or 해요체). The closest you can get in 하십시오체 is ㅂ니다 and -ㄴ뎁쇼(not used as much). But it can be expressed in 하십시오체 in many other ways.

> 비가 오는가 봅니다.
>
> A: 정장 입으셨습니까? 
> B: 면접 있습니다.

해체 is simple. Just strip off the 요.

> 비가 오네
>
> A: 정장 입었네. 
> B: 면접 있거든.

하오체(rarely used in speech)

> 비가 오오.
>
> A: 정장 입었구려. 
> B: 면접 있다오.

하게체(seldom used)

> 비가 오네. (-네 is a 하게체 ending too.)
>
> A: 정장 입었네그려. 
> B: 면접 있다네.

해라체.

> 비가 온다./오느니라.(archaic)/올데라니!(rare)/오니라.(archaic)
>
> A: 정장 입었구나.
> B: 면접 있단다.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer.  But I meant to ask about 해라체, not 해체 (now edited).    Could I use these somehow in 해라체?

Comment: Would it be ok and natural to switch from 합쇼체 to 해요체 momentarily to use  -거든요?

Comment: @gaeguri Yes, it's fine in most cases. When you're not in a formal situation, you're ought to use 해요체 anyway, except in some special cases like in the army. Also edited the answer to include 해라체. My mistake putting -구나 in the 해체 section.

Comment: 1. Wouldn't "비가 오나 봅니다" be more idiomatic than '비가 오는가 봅니다"? 2. How about "비온다" instead of "비가 오네" in 해체? 3. I think a question mark is necessary after "정장 입었네". 4. Is ending "있거든" 해체? 5. Wouldn't "정장 입었냐?" be better than "정장입었네" and "면접 있다" instead of "면접 있거든"?